# Javascript OOP - Function within return function

Tags: javascript, oop

Trying to create function call that only be called if other function has been called within same line.

```
var processTrack = new function() {
    this.current = 1;
    this.max = 5800;
    this.min = 0;
    this.done = function(started, processing, cur, len) {
        cur = cur || 0;
        len = len || 1;
        var res = 0;
        if (started && !processing)
            res = ((this.current - 1 - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)).toFixed(2);
        else if (!started && processing)
            res = (this.done(true, false) + (this.step() * this.cur / this.len)).toFixed(2);
        else if (!started && !processing)
            res = ((++this.current - 1 - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)).toFixed(2);

        this.percentage = function() {
            return res * 100 + "%";
        };
        return res;
    };
    this.step = function() {
        return 1 / (this.max - this.min);
    };
}
```

What I ideally want is to call `processTrack.done(args).percentage()` to get percentage from the data I recieved from `.done(args)`, but whenever I try to call (for example) `processTrack.done(true, false).percentage()` it gives me an error saying:

`TypeError: processTrack.done(...).percentage is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to call `.percentage()` on `res`, not on `this.done`. Try doing `res.percentage = function() ...; return res;`.

Comment: `this.done` must return `this`, not `res`.

Comment: But really, rethink this a bit. You probably don't want to put presentation logic in the function tracking progress.

Comment: Why `processTrack = new function()`? You can do `processTrack = function() {}` and use variables inside function scope, exposing only an object returned by the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `this` instead of `res` at the end of your `this.done` function. By returning `this`, you are returning your `this.done` function, which is the object that has the `percentage` function in it.

The following code runs without errors:

```
var processTrack = new function() {
    this.current = 1;
    this.max = 5800;
    this.min = 0;
    this.done = function(started, processing, cur, len) {
        cur = cur || 0;
        len = len || 1;
        var res = 0;
        if (started && !processing)
            res = ((this.current - 1 - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)).toFixed(2);
        else if (!started && processing)
            res = (this.done(true, false) + (this.step() * this.cur / this.len)).toFixed(2);
        else if (!started && !processing)
            res = ((++this.current - 1 - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)).toFixed(2);

        this.percentage = function() {
            return res * 100 + "%";
        };
        return this;
    };
    this.step = function() {
        return 1 / (this.max - this.min);
    };
}

processTrack.done(true, false).percentage();
```

Comment: Ah, so that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Return this in done method. As it is returning res which is not an object